# Cannot import namespace by using the USE

Tags: php, namespaces

I have three files `firstFile.php`, `secondFile.php`, and `thirdFile.php`.

firstFile looks like the below:

```
namespace test\main;

function hello () {
   echo 'from main';
}
```

secondFile looks like the below:

```
namespace test\second;

function hello () {
   echo 'from second';
}
```

thirdFile looks like the below:

```
use function test\main\hello;

echo hello();
```

My question is why `use function test\main\hello;` is working but when I use `use function test\second\hello;`, it then causes a fatal error: `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function test\second\hello()`?

Comment: Are you loading all the functions? Are you using an autoloader?

Comment: @CodeSpirit I'm using WordPress, the `firstFile.php` is actually the plugin's main file, and the `secondFile.php`, and `thirdFile.php` are the included files. I mean in the `firstFile.php`, it include the other two files.

Comment: The `use` statements don’t load any files, you must still `include` or `require` them somehow, either manually or through an autoloader

Comment: @ChrisHaas You're genius! May I know should the `include` before or after the `use`?

Comment: @doqgmui, the order does not matter. `use` just gives PHP context when it can’t resolve something, but by itself it doesn’t do anything which you can see here: https://3v4l.org/S5ODl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use all function in one file, it will with errors. Because all the content of files contain **hello** function. However, you need to use autoload.php or custom autoload schema. Otherwise, you may use require or include all this files before their using.

For example

```php
require "firstFile.php"
require "secondFile.php"

use function test\main\hello;
use function test\second\hello as secondHello;

echo hello();
echo secondHello();
```